# 'gensim.models.word2vec' has no attribute 'KeyedVectors'

Tags: python, word2vec

When running with Anaconda-python and apply gensim v3.4.0 can not use attribute `word2vec.KeyedVectors.load word2vec` format

How do I fix the problem?

```py
model1 = word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('text2_2.model.bin', binary=True)
```

Have error with comment:

```
AttributeError: module 'gensim.models.word2vec' has no attribute 'KeyedVectors'
```

Answer (score 0):

Word2Vec `gensim.models.word2vec` doesn't have a `load_word2vec_format` method, you should try `gensim.models.KeyedVectors` to load the bin file:

```
model1 = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(datapath("euclidean_vectors.bin"), binary=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct: the `gensim` module `word2vec` doesn't contain the class `KeyedVectors`. That class is in the `gensim.models` module.

As the [examples in the documentation for `KeyedVectors` show](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#how-to-obtain-word-vectors), it can be imported via...

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
```

...to then just refer to the class as `KeyedVectors`.

Or, as shown in the [sibling answer by @greg-paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58054017/130288), you could just use the correct fully-specified name, `gensim.models.KeyedVectors`, rather than anything referencing a `word2vec` module.